# I am trying to edit index-slider.php file in busiprof theme, but it doesn't change anything

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to edit index-slider.php file in busiprof theme, when I am done with changes and saved it but when i am reloading my page on the website it doesn't change, actually I tried removing some of the classes to check it's working or not but nothing has happened, What should I do? Please help

Comment: Clear the cache and check.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the file from admin panel or using FTP or file manager?

Please user FTP or File Manager and then please check the file permission as well then try clear cache if any caching plugin installed